# Print out all vowels not contained in a word

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm suppose to write a function that prints out all the vowels that does not appear in the word that is passed as a parameter.

Output is suppose to be:

```
>>> absentVowels('computer')
'ai'
>>> absentVowels('science')
'aou'
```

The code I have right now is this:

```
def absentVowels(word):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    answer = ''
    for i in word:
        if i in vowels:
            answer+=i
    return answer
```

and instead of my output being 'aou' for `absentVowels('science')` im getting vowels that are contained in that word which are, 'iee'

**EDIT:**
I actually need to use a iterator loop with an accumulator

Answer (score 4):

Use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference):

```
>>> set('aeiou').difference('computer')
set(['a', 'i'])
>>> ''.join(set('aeiou').difference('computer'))
'ai'
```

---

```
>>> ''.join(set('aeiou').difference('science'))
'auo'
>>> ''.join(sorted(set('aeiou').difference('science'))) # to get ordered result
'aou'
```

Comment: Or just: `set('aeiou') - set('computer')`

Comment: @Marcin, If you use `set.difference`, you don't need to convert the word into set.

Comment: Good answer, but probably not what the user needs to  understand :)

Comment: I actually haven't learned set.difference yet lol thats why i was having a bit of a trouble. Thank you!

Comment: @falsetru, do we have to add a string for Uppercase vowels as well?...as above code wont work for say, 'COMPuter' or 'SCIEnce'.

Comment: @PEJK, How about `set('aeiou').difference('COMPuter'.lower())`

Answer (score 1):

```
def absentVowels(word):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    present = set(char for char in word if char in vowels)
    print(''.join(sorted(vowels-present)))
```

Ouput:

```
In [160]: absentVowels('computer')
ai

In [161]: absentVowels('science')
aou
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate), which surprisingly would be faster compared to using set.difference

```
>>> 'aeiou'.translate(None, 'computer')
'ai'
>>> 'aeiou'.translate(None, 'science')
'aou'
```

[str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) accepts a third parameter `deletechars`, which deletes all characters from the string that are in deletechars before translating. As in the above case, translate table is None, no translation happenns.

Comment: I agree, but I was thinking doing this with a loop and using an accumulator

Comment: @yummyyenni: And what harm this will pose if you do it in a loop? Moreover, I did not get the part of using an accumulator

Comment: oh nothing at all, your way is much better, but my professor wanted us to do it in that way using loop. If it was my way, I would of definitely ditched that and would do what you did here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of your original code that doesn't use list comprehensions, generator expressions, or sets.

Due to the way Python handles strings and lists it's not so efficient to use a string as an accumulator, it's better to accumulate things into a list and then join the list into a string, if necessary.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def absentVowels(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'    
    answer = []
    for i in vowels:
        if i not in word:
            answer += [i]
    return ''.join(answer)


def main():
    words = 'computer science'.split()
    for word in words:
        print word, absentVowels(word)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
computer ai
science aou
```

Note that `answer += [i]` could also be written as `answer.append(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some fine examples here. In your code you are returning the vowels that are present in the in the word. To get the vowels which are not in the word you can modify your code like this,

```
def absentVowels(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    avails = ''
    for i in word:
        if i in vowels:
            avails += i
    answer = ''.join(s for s in vowels if s not in avails)
    return answer
```

Here `answer` is a string of concatenated characters in `vowels` which are not present in `avail` or available vowels in the word.